# Does anyone know why background image isn't displaying?

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm creating a website following a tutorial and got stuck (lol). I don't know why the background image isn't displaying. Tried to rename classes etc but nothing works. Could anyone give me a hint?

```
.site-main .subscribe-us-area .subscribe {
  background: url(/img/subscribe-bg.png) no-repeat;
  padding: 10rem 0;
  margin: 3rem auto;
}


<section class="subscribe-us-area">
  <div class="container subscribe">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center subscribe-title">
              <h4 class="text-uppercase">Get Update From anywhere</h4>
              <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam,
                  consequuntur.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-center">
          <form class="w-50">
              <div class="row d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
                  <div class="col input-textbox">
                      <input type="text" id="txtemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col">
                      <div class="btn-submit">
                          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">Subscribe</button>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I want the image to be displayed in the background

Comment: Have you try add *comma(,)* each class? ```.site-main, .subscribe-us-area, .subscribe```. Also your image url need a *qoute*. ```background: url("/img/subscribe-bg.png") no-repeat;``` and make sure the path is correct.

Comment: We can not tell if your selector matches (because there is no element with class `site-main` in your code.) Go use your browser dev tools to find out if the rule applied to the element to begin with. Also go check the console and/or network panel, to see if there are any 404 errors in there that would indicate that you simply got the path wrong.

Comment: @Newbee _"Have you try add comma(,) each class?"_ - that would make it something completely different. `.subscribe-us-area` and `.subscribe` are directly nested - so it is rather unlikely, that they want to apply the background image to _multiple_ elements here. _"Also your image url need a qoute."_ - no, it does not. Those are optional.

Comment: @Newbee Yes I tried commas. Added a quote and still not working :(

Comment: @CBroe  There is such class and works for other elements but for some reason not for this, I'll add a small piece: <!-- Start Main Area -->
 <main class="site-main">
  <!-- Start Banner Area -->
  <section class="site-banner">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12">
          <h3 class="title-text text-uppercase">Hey</h3>
          <h1 class="title-text">I am XX</h1>
          <h4 class="title-text text-uppercase">Junior Web Developer</h4>
      <div class="site-buttons">

Comment: I am not sure how that last piece of code is supposed to clarify anything. And I already asked you to please use your browser dev tools, and investigate the issue. You could show code all day long here, that would still not tell us whether the path you used for the image is actually correct, within your overall setup.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the code supplied by @Tasye to work (adding the . in front of the url). I also had to add a the class= "site-main" to a div. This looks something like this:

```
  <style>
  .site-main .subscribe-us-area .subscribe {
   background: url(./img/subscribe-bg.png) no-repeat;
   padding: 10rem 0;
   margin: 3rem auto;
  }
  </style>
<body class="site-main">
  <section class="subscribe-us-area">
     <div class="container subscribe">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-lg-12 text-center subscribe-title">
             <h4 class="text-uppercase">Get Update From anywhere</h4>
             <p class="para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam,
              consequuntur.</p>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-sm-flex justify-content-center">
          <form class="w-50">
            <div class="row d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
              <div class="col input-textbox">
                  <input type="text" id="txtemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
              </div>
              <div class="col">
                  <div class="btn-submit">
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">Subscribe</button>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
       </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

try doing this:

```css
.site-main .subscribe-us-area .subscribe {
     background: url("./img/subscribe-bg.png") no-repeat;
}
```

[see this documentation from mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/CSS/background#syntax)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working